# Effects of Hawan/Yajna on health

Tags: yajna

How does the smoke from hawan/yajna affect the health of the human beings inhaling it? Are there any good effects?

How does its effects compare with those of vehicle exhaust/industrial pollution? I'm looking for an answer which might provide a breakdown of the constituents of hawan's smoke e.g. gases, particulate matter, their size etc.

Comment: Well comparison should be between two at par things .... pollution is a major issue for it's everywhere coz of vehicles, industries, construction etc etc ... but how many hawans/yajnas are there on daily basis?? Just asking your opinion.

Comment: Actually I've asked this question as hawan is done daily by my mother. That's why I'm concerned. I'm looking for an answer which might provide a breakdown of the constituents of hawan's smoke e.g. gases, particulate matter, their size etc.

Comment: Question is off-topic for the site as you are asking about the science behind yajnas. For the current times, pollution from yajnas is no different from industrial and vehicle pollution. Check [this article](https://www.newsclick.in/burn-wood-reduce-pollution).

Comment: I think the havan dhuan is not as bad for you as car exhaust (??) or pollution cigarette smoke etc…those stuffs are injurious to health, bad effects lungs etc